# Update sql not being executed for my component Joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

I am trying to add a few new columns to certain tables in Joomla, since i need to migrate these fixes from dev to production i am trying to do this the clean way, updates trough the filesystem.

I have followed a few tutorials concerning this and did the following.

I created the folder updates/sql and put a new sql file in it with my new version (1.5).
I changed the version number in my xml file.
I refreshed my cache in the backend.

Here are the codes I used:

My version:

```
<version>1.5</version>
```

The update node:

```
<update>
        <schemas>
            <schemapath type="mysql">sql/updates/mysql</schemapath>
            <schemapath type="sqlsrv">sql/updates/sqlsrv</schemapath>
            <schemapath type="sqlazure">sql/updates/sqlazure</schemapath>
        </schemas>
</update>
```

The sql file:

```
ALTER TABLE `#__mycomponent` ADD `field` VARCHAR(255);
```

I tested my query directly against the database and it worked, what am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer - Joomla!'s DB migration tool only does them after uploading a new component via the Component Manager. It doesn't check for a migration on every $_REQUEST, which is what your question suggests.

**Longer Answer**

Make sure you run the upgrade via the component manager. Simply over-writing the files doesn't trigger Joomla's migration process. Check the #__schemas table for your component's ID, and it'll have a corresponding database schema version #. If that version hasn't incremented yet, then the migration wasn't applied.

*Part of the problem is*

> I am trying to do this the clean way, updates trough the filesystem

While I agree with you, that would be the clean way: Joomla! wants you to do things the Joomla! way ;-)

***Important Note about Joomla! SQL Files***

SQL files cannot contain C style comments (`# comment here`), and must contain comments like this `-- comment here` Spent a few hours debugging my own code, and had to re-run an upgrade about 25 times to figure out where the database schema migration was failing.

Comments may support the `/* Comment  */` style syntax, but I have yet to test that as extensively. YMMV.